# Editing Product Options Using the Shopify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to edit a product's option values in Shopify. Essentially, I want to pass a reordered array for `products[0].options[0].values`

[image]

Using Shopify's [REST API docs](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/product#put-products-product-id), I make a request like so:

```
import {Product} from '@shopify/shopify-api/dist/rest-resources/2021-10/index.js';

const test_session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(request, response);

const product = new Product({session: test_session});

product.id = 7758005469437;

product.options[0].values = newOptionsOrder;

await product.save({});
```

I get the following error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

I was successfuly able to edit the title of the target product using `product.title = "New Title";` The issue just seems to be targeting more nested elements.

Any idea how to edit the first options.values array?

Comment: From the provided error  `product.options` is `undefined` in your case and you can't get the first element of undefined object. Log your `product` object and check what is the response since it seems the current products you've selected just doesn't have any options object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Turns out I was unnecessarily instantiating another version of ```product``` which didn't need to be created.